# Unable to redirect my form to a new html page. Its going to localhost:3000/confirm.html instead i want it to open confirm.html in a new window

Tags: javascript, html

In the below code, after clicking on 'Save Data' I want the page to go to another htm page 'confrim.html'. Instead what is happening is its just showing "localhost:3000/confirm.html" and not opening a new page. Can anyone help to fix this, attaching the code for the reference.
I tried to implement the following through the submitInfo() function
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
 <style>
 * {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 border-color: teal;
}
html{
      background : radial-gradient(rgba(48, 97, 97, 0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5))
  }
div {
    padding: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
 font-size: 25px;
 font-style: initial;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
}

.input[type=button]{ 
    font: 25px Calibri;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
 padding: 7px;
 color: teal;
 font-size: 30px;
}
#bt{
      width : 190px;
      height: 60px;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;    
      background-color: #05193d;
      color: whitesmoke;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      margin-top: 10px;
  }


input[type=text], textarea, select {
    font: 17px Calibri;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
 border-radius: 4px;
 color:teal
}
 </style>
 
 <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
    <h1>User Information </h1>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
</head>
<body>
 
    <div>
        <form name="myForm" action="confirm.html" method="POST" >
        <!--Add few elements to the form-->

        <div>
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your Email Id" />
  </div>  
  <div>
            <label for="Controller Type">Controller Type</label>
            <select id="selProd">
            <option value=""> - Select the Controller - </option>
      <option value="RAID">RAID</option>
      <option value="JBOD">JBOD</option>
      <option value="EBOD">EBOD</option>
      <option value="AP">AP</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Test Type">Test Type    </label>
            <select id="selTest">
                <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
    <option value="BFT">BFT</option>
    <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
    <option value="Channel">Channel</option>
    <option value="DVT" >DVT</option>
            </select>
        </div>
  <div>
            <label for="Protocol Type">Protocol Type    </label>
            <select id="selProto">
                <option value=""> - Select The Protocol - </option>
    <option value="SAS">SAS</option>
    <option value="iSCSI">iSCSI</option>
    <option value="FC">FC</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="IP Address">IP Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtIP" placeholder="Enter your IP address" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Chasis Input">Number of Chasis Input:</label>
            <input type="number" id="txtInputs" placeholder="Enter Number of Chasis" />
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Save data" onclick="submitInfo()"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="bt" value="Save data to file" onclick="saveFile()" />
        </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 <script>


 let saveFile = () => {
     
  // Get the data from each element on the form.
    const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
  const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
  const test = document.getElementById('selTest');
  const product = document.getElementById('selProd');
  const protocol = document.getElementById('selProto');
  const IP = document.getElementById('txtIP');
  const Inputs = document.getElementById('txtInputs');
  
  // This variable stores all the data.
   
  let data = 
    '\rName : ' + name.value + '\r\n' +
    'Email ID : ' + email.value + '\r\n' +
    'Test Type : ' + test.value + '\r\n' +
    'Product Type : ' + product.value + '\r\n' +
    'Protocol Type : ' + protocol.value + '\r\n' +
    'IP Address : ' + IP.value + '\r\n' +
    'Chasis Inputs : ' + Inputs.value;
  

    if(name.value =='' || email.value == '' || test.value =='' || product.value =='' || IP.value  == ''|| Inputs.value == ''){
        alert("Please fill all the fields!");
        return;
  }

    const reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    if (reg.test(email.value) == false) 
        {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            return false;
        }
  
  var ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
  if (ipformat.test(IP.value) == false) 
        {
            alert('Invalid IP Address');
            return false;
        }
     
    if(name.value.length<3){
  alert("Name must be having atleast 3 Characters");
  return;
  }
  
    if(name.value == ''){
   alert("Enter the name First");
  }

   
   
  // Convert the text to BLOB.
  const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
  const sFileName = 'formData.yaml';    // The file to save the data.
   
  let newLink = document.createElement("a");
  newLink.download = sFileName;
  

  if (window.webkitURL != null) {
   newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
  }
  else {
   newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
   newLink.style.display = "none";
   document.body.appendChild(newLink);
  }

   
  newLink.click();
 }
 var disable_options = false;
 document.getElementById('selProd').onchange = function () {
     //alert("selected value = "+this.value);
     if(this.value == "RAID")
     {
            document.getElementById('selProto').removeAttribute('disabled');

     }
     else
     {
            document.getElementById('selProto').setAttribute('disabled', true);
     }
   }  
   
 function submitInfo(){
  var test = document.getElementById('selTest').value;
  var product = document.getElementById('selProd').value;

  if(product == "EBOD" && test== "BFT"){
 window.location ="confirm.html";
  }
}   
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `window.open` method - like so:

```
function submitInfo(){
    var test = document.getElementById('selTest').value;
    var product = document.getElementById('selProd').value;

    if( product == "EBOD" && test== "BFT" ){
        window.open( "confirm.html", "Confirm", "fullscreen=yes,location=no,menubar=yes,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no" );
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a seperate file confirm.html :-
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <h1>More Details Required</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="IP Address">IP Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtIP" placeholder="Enter your IP address" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Chasis Input">Number of Chasis Input:</label>
        <input type="number" id="txtInputs" placeholder="Enter Number of Chasis" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I want the following to be shown in a new window when i click on Save Data button, its opening the same page right now

Comment: They cannot both be called `confirm.html` in the same directory - confused.com

Comment: why not just amend these fields in the original form if the conditions specified in submitInfo are met rather than make another page ( which incidentally would post to?? )

Comment: By using your technique of window.open. I was able to open a new window and the page is going to confirm.html as well yet the contents of that page is not shown. its just showing the original page itself.
There is only one file named as 'confirm.html' in my present directory

Comment: I undertsand - this was not made clear in the original question but the snippet posted in the comment above clarifies what you are trying to do. Opening a new window with additional form elements is possible - but there are issues to overcome and it is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I tried amending in the same  form but failed to do so. Tried using Modal Form, prompt but nothing seemed to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206497/discussion-between-pyhton-learner-and-ramraider).

Answer (score 0):

you have a

```
<form name="myForm" action="confirm.html" method="POST" >
```

which, on form submit, your browser will look for confirm.html file. I don't know whether you have file named confirm.html, but I think you do. otherwise it'll show 404 error.

As you instructed in your form, browser'll look for **confirm.html**, and on redirect, it'll show what's in confirm.html file.

you should remove your js script from this file and put it inside confirm.html file. or just replace **action="confirm.html"** with **action=""**

Comment: Yes, I have a separate file confirm.html. Right now what is happening is when i click on 'Save Data' its showing going to the page localhost:3000/confirm.html still the same page which was there in localhost:3000 is visible. Below is the confirm.html file:-

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <h1>More Details Required</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="IP Address">IP Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtIP" placeholder="Enter your IP address" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>